# How can i implements an online chat?

Tags: xmpp, chat, vs-web-site-project, instant-messaging

Ok, let's say that there's a company (let's say e-commerce) that has to implement a support chat on its website. Do you know what are protocols/infrastructures needed?

I've seen XMPP but I don't know if it's really useful in my case...

Ty a lot!

Comment: Isn't better to use a ready-made solution?

Comment: Yeah, probably it would, but I have to design a more specific one

Answer (score 1):

If you need to implement all things yourself, and don't want to use XMPP server, you can create your own chat protocol.

Such a protocol can be based on [JSON-RPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification). 
Also, you can make a simple protocol using only features from [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/). 
You can use Socket.IO both on the server and client-side.

You will also need a database for storing chats and messages. 
If you anticipate very heavy traffic, you can use e.g [Apache CASSANDRA](https://cassandra.apache.org/), but a plain SQL (or noSQL) database will be sufficient for most implementations. 
It is better to use a database you are familiar with. The [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) can be a good choice because it has nice JSON support. 
If you prefer a noSQL database, [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) will be OK.

If you use React, for the frontend I recommend you to use a [@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react](https://github.com/chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react) components together with the [@chatscope/use-chat](https://github.com/chatscope/use-chat) library (I'm the author of both of them).